# Trouble displaying data on a list

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am trying to display information on a list using an ArrayAdapter, and where the information are retrieved from Parse.com. To achieve this, I have created a listview in my layout, and have attempted to relate my listview in the code below. In doing so, I have encounter a few errors that I am having difficulty resolving.

In particular, I receive the following error for the below line
"The method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter) is undefined for the type List"

```
 mUsers.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I have been able to retrieve the following information:

```
           mParseUser.getString("name");
           mParseUser.getNumber("age"); 
           mParseUser.getString("headline");
```

However, I want to display that in my the application, and was thinking initially of using a listview.

Below is my activity code
    public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {

```
    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;   
    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
         //create list variable
        mUsers = (List<ParseUser>) findViewById(R.id.listView1);



    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();


        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {



                  //add all the users to your list variable 
                    mUsers.addAll(users); 



                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                }
            }
        });

        //check the size of your list to see how big it is before accessing it
        final int size = mUsers.size(); 

       //or use a loop to loop through each one
        for(ParseUser mParseUser : mUsers)
        {
              //skip over the current user
           if(mParseUser == ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
               continue; 

           mParseUser.getString("name");
           mParseUser.getNumber("age"); 
           mParseUser.getString("headline");

           ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                   this, 
                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Unsure what to input here, 
                   as I want to return all three items (name, age, headline) from parse into the list);
           mUsers.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

    }
    }
```

Below is my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Update
The code now uses ParseQueryAdapter, but I have encountered a few errors such has:

"The type new ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method 
 ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener.onLoaded(List, Exception)"

In particular, the above error was found in the following section:

```
// Perhaps set a callback to be fired upon successful loading of a new set of ParseObjects.
         adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {
           public void onLoading() {
             // Trigger any "loading" UI
           }
```

In the following lines

```
  public ParseQuery create() {
                 ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("User");

                 query.orderByDescending("name");
                 return query;
               }
             };
```

I have set "User" has the class name, and "name" has string value of the class. How would I also include other items like "headline" string value and "age" number value into the query list as well.

The complete code is as follow:

```
// Instantiate a QueryFactory to define the ParseQuery to be used for fetching items in this
 // Adapter.
 ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
     new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
       public ParseQuery create() {
         ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Customer");
         query.whereEqualTo("activated", true);
         query.orderByDescending("moneySpent");
         return query;
       }
     };

 // Pass the factory into the ParseQueryAdapter's constructor.
 ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory);
 adapter.setTextKey("name");

 // Perhaps set a callback to be fired upon successful loading of a new set of ParseObjects.
 adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {
   public void onLoading() {
     // Trigger any "loading" UI
   }

   public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
     // Execute any post-loading logic, hide "loading" UI
   }
 });

 // Attach it to your ListView, as in the example above
 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Update 2**
Below is the updated code
I have made the following adjustments

1) added  @Override  on top of public void onloading
2) changed ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("User"); to ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("User");

due to the following message "
ParseQuery is a raw type. References to generic type ParseQuery should be parameterized"

Below is the updated code

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {


    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;   
    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);
        // Instantiate a QueryFactory to define the ParseQuery to be used for fetching items in this
         // Adapter.
         ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
             new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
               public ParseQuery create() {
                 ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("User");

                 query.orderByDescending("name");
                 return query;
               }
             };

         // Pass the factory into the ParseQueryAdapter's constructor.
         ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory);
         adapter.setTextKey("name");

         // callback to be fired upon successful loading of a new set of ParseObjects.
         adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {
             @Override 
             public void onLoading() {
             // Trigger any "loading" UI
           }

           public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
             // Execute any post-loading logic, hide "loading" UI
           }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
         });

         // Attach it to your ListView, as in the example above
         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSingleClick);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
        }
```

**Update 3**

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {


    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;   
    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);
        // Instantiate a QueryFactory to define the ParseQuery to be used for fetching items in this
         // Adapter.
         ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
             new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
               public ParseQuery create() {
                 ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("User");
                query.setLimit(5);
                 query.orderByDescending("name");
                 return query;
               }
             };

         // Pass the factory into the ParseQueryAdapter's constructor.
         ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory);
         adapter.setTextKey("name");

         // callback to be fired upon successful loading of a new set of ParseObjects.
         adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {
             @Override 
             public void onLoading() {
             // Trigger any "loading" UI
           }



        @Override
        public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
         });

         // Attach it to your ListView, as in the example above
         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSingleClick);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ParseQueryAdapter https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/?com/parse/ParseObject.html? 
I think it is the best way to fetch data from Parse and display it as a list.
If you want to use some simple mappings between data in list and visual representation of a list just create new ParseQueryAdapter and select columns from that you will fetch data to image and to text field of ListView item.

```
   ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<>(this, ParseUser.class);
   adapter.setTextKey("username");
   adapter.setImageKey("userpic");
   mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Check this tutorial https://www.parse.com/tutorials/mealspotting it will help you

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I have looked into the suggested links, and have attempted to adjust the code as such. I have encounter a few issues and concerns while doing so and have indicated it under the update section of my initial post. I would appreciate if you could kindly take a look at it. Thanks alot.

Comment: Did I correctly realize that you want to display in your listview rows also "headline" and "age"?

Comment: So, first of all you have to create Parse Class on parse.com with columns for all data you want to store in it. Then you have to create Java-class extend ParseObject class and declare in it fields representing that columns. Then you have to create custom layout for the row of your listview. Finally you have to extend ParseQueryAdapter and override getView() method where you have to inflate your custom view and bind View widgets with data. That's all, you don't need to make queries, ParseQueryAdapter will make it for you

Comment: And don't forget to call registerSubclass() method before using your class that extends  Parse-object

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, and for all of the information provided. The parse class have already been created with the name "user" and where the column have already been created, and data is already stored there. The issue resolves in retrieving it. I have tried to use parsequeryadapter has shown under the update section of my initial post but that have unfortunatetly been unsuccesful.

Comment: in the above code you've missed @Override annotations before implementations of OnQueryLoadListener interface methods

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response. I have tried to apply your suggestions, and made a minor adjustment in ParseQuery. Unfortunately, when the activity loads, it is still blank. So I am not too sure what went wrong. The "User" represents the class names, and strings such "name", "age", and "headline" represent the columns. I have updated the code and my few concerns under update 2 of my initial post. Thanks for your suggestion so far, and it would be helpful if you could kindly advise on this matter.

Comment: why do you use onQueryLoadListener with empty methods in it?
Then you have two onLoaded() methods in it - remove one that not overrides abstract method
Also in onLoaded() method check the length of received list. Maybe you need to cast received list of ParseObject to your custom class
Then try not to use QueryFactory, simply create ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> and see what's happened

Comment: Thanks for your advice, and suggestions. I have updated my code under update 3 of my initial post. Avoiding using QueryFactory seems difficult since its refereed to in many parts of the code.